# Does a connection exist between the roots of $\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$ and the roots of its derivative?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, asymptotics, roots

From the answer to this question [about the complex roots of $\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638029/is-there-a-pattern-in-the-complex-roots-of-the-sine-integral-mathrmsi-left), we now know that the asymptotic of the $k$-th complex root $z_k = x_k + i y_k $ is:

\begin{align}
x_k &\approx 4\pi k - \frac{{\log k}}{{\pi k}} \\
\\
y_k &\approx 2\log x_k + 2\log (\pi /2)
\end{align}

The Hadamard product for $\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$ is:

$$\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) = \frac{z}{2}\,\prod_{z_k} \left(1-\frac{z}{z_k} \right) \tag{1}$$

with $z_k$ taken as quadruples $z_k, -z_k, \overline{z_k}, -\overline{z_k}$.

The logarithmic derivative of the RHS of (1) then becomes:

$$\frac{\mathrm{Si}'}{\mathrm{Si}}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) = \sum_{z_k} \frac{1}{z-z_k} + \frac{1}{z}\tag{2}$$

hence,

$$\mathrm{Si}'\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{z} =\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\,\left( \sum_{z_k} \frac{1}{z-z_k} + \frac{1}{z}\right)\tag{3}$$

So, the regular real roots of $\displaystyle \frac{\sin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{z}$, i.e. $\mu_m = \pm 2\pi m$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}$, will occur when:

$$\sum_{z_k} \frac{1}{z-z_k} = -\frac{1}{z} \tag{4}$$

**Question:**

Suppose we only know the asymptotic for the complex roots $z_k$ of $\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$, could we then derive, e.g. using (4), any information/constraints about the location of the real roots $\mu_m$ of its derivative $\mathrm{Si}'\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$?

Potentially related questions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48809/relationships-between-the-roots-of-an-entire-function-and-the-roots-of-its-deriv), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047004/relation-between-roots-of-function-and-roots-of-its-derivative) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349202/roots-of-a-polynomial-and-its-derivative).